# jQuery: How to refresh data being read from a cookie after the cookie is updated in an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a billing form that reads data from a cookie and prefills the fields based on the cookie value.  If a user changes the field, they can click 'save' which triggers an AJAX call and upon that success, I update the cookie with the new field values.  How can I have the page refresh without actually reloading it.

```
let address = `<input class="street-address inner-inputs" value='${Cookies.getJSON('braintreeData') && Cookies.getJSON('braintreeData').streetAddress || ""}'></input>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen remove() and then append() the html again but it's simply not feasible for me to do that.

Comment: @RaymonOpie it is the only way if he got radios/checkboxes. Best you can do is create a JS method to generate the form using cookie values, and then you can remove it and create it any time.

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is do what RaymonOpie and darklightcode said, its the best solution